# log4j truncates log message when the log size is above threshold size

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

In my project there are few logs appearing which are very large. I want to specify the threshold size of log, so that whenever  there is any large log message appearing  which is above the threshold size, log4J will truncate the message and truncation should be at the end of the message.

Comment: See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout, (search for `maxLen`).

Comment: It is possible to implement the behavior you mentioned. Log4J supports creating custom "Layout". For this, you can implement your own "TruncatingLayout" class, which derives from the Layout<String> class. However, I have concerns about doing this. Since such an application will affect all logs, it will probably cause other problems later. Isn't it possible to silence the relevant log at its source? Or adding a custom Appender rather than using Layout might be a solution. With a custom appender, you can control the behavior of each log event before it gets written out.